# Inheritance : call a derived class function from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is possible in C++ to make this?

```
class Base {
     int a(Derived d) { d.b(); } 
 };

 class Derived : public Base {
    int b();
 };
```

Should i include Derived.hpp even in Base.hpp?

Comment: Make `b()` a pure virtual function in `Base`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: With forward declaration, and split declaration from definition, your sample may work. But I am not sure that what you show is really what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible in C++ to make this?

Yes, it's very easy and a basic pattern (called polymorphism or [Template Method Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1)) used in the c++ language:

```
class Base {
     int a() { b(); } // Note there's no parameter needed!
// Just provide a pure virtual function declaration in the base class
protected:    
     virtual int b() = 0;

 };

 class Derived : public Base {
    int b();
 };
```

Comment: You have to remember not to call such functions in constructor or desctructor, otherwise you'll end up with pure function call.

Comment: @paweldac Fortunately that's not the case in the OP's sample. If there's need to do so your answer fixes that problem.

Comment: just wanted to make it clear to other readers that might use proposed code. True that in OPs question, this error won't come up :)

Comment: @paweldac I'm out of votes for today, sorry. Otherwise I would have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles:

```
class Derived;

class Base {
public:
    int a(Derived d);
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int b() { return 42; }
};

int Base::a(Derived d) { d.b(); }
```

Comment: It compiles, yes. Though I'm afraid that's not what's being asked here (as you mentioned in the comment).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to call functions from Derived class from Base class with C++ idiom called: "Curiously recurring template pattern" CRTP. Please find call below:

```
template <class Child> 
struct Base
{
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<Child*>(this)->bar();
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's another way to do it, yes.